# How to make a set of unique records in Elm

Tags: elm

I need a set of unique records. But Elm Core's `Set` restricts set members to `comparable`:

```
import Set exposing (Set)

mySet = Set.empty
Set.insert {name="Foo"} mySet
```

```
-- TYPE MISMATCH ----------------------------------------------------------- elm

The 1st argument to `insert` is not what I expect:

6|   Set.insert {name="Foo"} mySet
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
This argument is a record of type:

    { name : String }

But `insert` needs the 1st argument to be:

    comparable

Hint: Only ints, floats, chars, strings, lists, and tuples are comparable.
```

How do you make a set of records in Elm?

Comment: was my suggestion useful?

Comment: Yes! I wanted to wait a little in case some other magical solution was suggested. Your answer is the correct one I believe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the standard library you can't. As noted in the "Hint" you could use a tuple, but these are limited to 3-tuples in 0.19.

So, I think your best bet is to use https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/Gizra/elm-all-set/latest/EverySet

Comment: https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/erlandsona/assoc-set/latest/AssocSet is an alternative. They're essentially the same package, based on the same underlying `AssocList` package. The difference is that `AssocSet`'s type is called `Set`, and can be used as a replacement for core's `Set` without renaming.